# php POST, GET, PUT, DELETE testing

Tags: php, request

Well, "created script":

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
switch($method) {
    case 'PUT':
        echo 'put method';
    break;
    case 'GET':
        echo 'get method';
    break;
    case 'POST':
        echo 'post method';
    break;
    case 'DELETE':
        echo 'delete method';
    default:
        echo 'valid method\'s: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE';
}
```

1. What's is best/simplest way to test each method ?

Wanna test them because actually in each method exist different task.

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Comment: The code in your Q seems a good test?

Comment: You should probably output a `405 Method Not Allowed` status for the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script that makes one or more HTTP requests (containing known data) for each method to the URI that the script you are testing resides at.

After each request the script should check that the response is as you expect it and that any side effects (such as the creation of files on the server, or entries in a database have changed) are as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Set up a form with a particular action:

```
<form action="your_page.php" method="PUT">
    <input type="submit" value="Put me!" />
</form>
<form action="your_page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Post me!" />
</form>
<form action="your_page.php" method="DELETE">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete me!" />
</form>
```

For "GET" you can just send in a querystring by calling your URL and appending `?key=value`

Comment: Well that's stupid. What's the point of having a `method="XXXXX"` if you can only put 2 of the 4 important verbs inside it?

Comment: — For `PUT` you'd need to add additional rules to the form such as "The body of the form must contain exactly one file input and one submit input". It would make even less sense to use a form to `DELETE` something as there is no use input being gathered at all, it would just remove the resource at the `action`.